# Why does this still look like bytes after I convert it to Unicode?

Tags: python, unicode

I have everything working as I want it in my code, but I'm still curious. I have a string: "stación." When I convert that string to unicode, I get:

```
unicode('stación', 'utf-8')
>>> u'staci\xf3n'
```

That "\xf3" in there looks like a byte character. This is different from:

```
unicode('Поиск', 'utf-8')
>>> u'\u041f\u043e\u0438\u0441\u043a'
```

In the latter example, as with everything I've converted to unicode before, I get unicode characters starting with "\u." Normally, when I see a byte starting with "\x," I think there's a problem. What gives here? Is this because "ó" is extended ASCII?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's because "ó" is a non-ASCII character within the first 255 characters. Since it's representable using a single byte, we save 2 characters in the representation. The other two representations are valid, but not required.

```
>>> u'\u00f3'
u'\xf3'
>>> u'\U000000f3'
u'\xf3'
```

Comment: I don't understand (novice on utf-8). I thought if the high order bit of a byte in utf-8 is 1, that the character was at least 2 bytes long.

Comment: But why is '\xf3' preferred over '\u00f3'? Is there some benefit to representing it this way?

Comment: It might be better to stress the difference between bytes and Unicode strings i.e., you could say "its Unicode ordinal (`243`) is representable using a single byte" instead of *"it's representable using a single byte"*.

Answer (score 0):

`u'\xf3'` is not a byte; it is a Unicode string with a single Unicode codepoint ([`U+00f3 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE`](http://codepoints.net/U+00f3)).

What you see (`u'\xf3'`) is how Python 2 chooses to represent Unicode character with Unicode ordinals (integers) in the range `0..255` that are not printable ascii characters (Python 3 would show `'ó'` here, only non-printable characters use `'\xhh'` form there by default). As [@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28998735/4279): `u'\u00f3'` and `u'\U000000f3'` literals create exactly the same Unicode string.

You could see how the Unicode character (`u'\xf3'`) looks like bytes in different character encodings for comparision:

```
>>> print(u'\xf3')
ó
>>> u'\xf3'.encode('utf-8')
b'\xc3\xb3'
>>> u'\xf3'.encode('utf-16be')                                                                            
b'\x00\xf3'
>>> u'\xf3'.encode('utf-32le')                                                                            
b'\xf3\x00\x00\x00'
>>> u'\xf3'.encode('cp1252')
b'\xf3'
```

Note: `b'\xf3'` and `u'\xf3'` are different things. The former is a bytestring that contains a single byte (an integer `243`), the latter is a Unicode string that contains a single Unicode codepoint (Unicode ordinal `243`). The number is the same `243` by the units are different -- 100 calories is not the same thing as 100 grams.